# How to have a figure going over several pages?

Tags: floats, longtable, subfloats

I have several images placed side-by-side. The number of images is too big to fit on one page. Is there a environment for figure which is able to go across pages without cutting the images into parts? The desired behavior would be similar to the behavior of `longtable`.

This is my current code:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering


   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{images/img_1}%
   \hspace{.25cm}%
   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{images/img_2}\\ \vspace{.25cm}%

   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{images/img_3}%
   \hspace{.25cm}%
   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{images/img_4} \\ \vspace{.25cm}%

   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{images/img_5}%
   \hspace{.25cm}%
   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{images/img_6}
  \caption{
      \small{This is a caption.}
      }
  \label{fig:results}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The concept of floats does usually not allow page breaking. One of your options would be to not use a float and just issue a `\captionof` after all of your pictures.

Another version: Use the `caption` package (which btw makes changing the font size easier) and its `\ContinuedFloat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{example-image.pdf}%
   \hspace{.25cm}%
   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{example-image.pdf}\\ \vspace{.25cm}%

   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{example-image.pdf}%
   \hspace{.25cm}%
   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{example-image.pdf} \\ \vspace{.25cm}%
   \caption{This is a caption.}
  \label{fig:results}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \ContinuedFloat
   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{example-image.pdf}%
   \hspace{.25cm}%
   \includegraphics[width=6.3cm]{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{This is a caption.}
  \label{fig:results}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```